# How to set/update PATH variable in elastic beanstalk?

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I can use it from EC2 instance. Even i can see the location added to PATH.
But when try to execute that script/path/program using nodejs child process, it is not available.
I think the path/shell that i am adding is different that the one being used in the deployed version of eb.

```
04_set_path:
    test: test ! -f /opt/elasticbeanstalk/.post-provisioning-complete
    command: echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/opt/gradle/gradle-7.3/bin' >> /root/.bash_profile
```

Check by connecting to ec2 console, and it is there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

At that point, those variables are not present during server provision/deployment.

In this case, you can

a) call the desired command using the full path or

b) you can use [platform hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html).

Using platform hooks you can have access to the environment variables thus the PATH like you have a real bash.